# Deletion from B-Tree - M=5

Tags: algorithm, tree, b-tree

I'm dealing with a deletion in BTree in very specific case

M=5 - that is - maximum number of keys in node is 4 and minimum number of keys in node is 2

Now when deleting in BTree using the defensive approach (I must use this one) when I approach a node I must guarantee that it has one key more than the minimum required.

Here is my problem - let's say I have a root with one key and two children with 2 keys each.
When I will approach one of these children I will have to guarantee that it has at least 3 keys (because M=5).

I have two ways to do it - borrow from neighbor or borrow from father and merge. I can't borrow from neighbor as it has the minimum of 2 keys but borrowing from the father and merging creates a node with 5 keys - and it's more than the maximum of the allowed keys (as M=5).

What should I do in this case?
More specifically - what is the correct way to treat such situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical B-trees constrain key counts for non-root nodes to lie between d and 2d for some d. This means that merging of nodes is only possible if an underflow has **already occurred** and the other node involved in the merge has minimum occupancy. Together with the separator key pulled from the parent node this makes for a key count of (d - 1) + d + 1 = 2d, which is the maximum that fits into a node. Merging on the way down 'just in case' is not possible.

Comment: Thanks @DarthGizka! 
This is indeed the classic B-Tree approach - that M is even!